# Find a good function for applying fixed-point iteration method on $f(x)=x^3-x^2-x-1$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

***Question:***

> We are given a function $f(x)=x^3-x^2-x-1$ and we know that the only positive root of $f$ is somewhere near to $\alpha=1.839$ . The goal is to find an approximation of the root of $f$ using fixed-point iteration method such that for every initial point ($x_0$), the sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$ converges to the fixed-point of $g$, which is also the root of $f$.

***My try:***

We have learned a theorem which states that if a function like $g$ has two properties, then the sequence made by it always converges to the fixed-point of the function, regardless of the initial point $x_0$.  The two properties are:

1) $\text{Range}(g)\subseteq  \text{Domain}(g) $

2) $\exists k \lt1  \quad \forall x\in \text{Domain}(g)\quad |g'(x)|<k$

So, with this knowledge, I tried to find a $g$ which holds these conditions, But I wasn't successful. I tried $g_1(x)=x^3-x^2-1$, $g_2(x)=\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}$ , $g_3(x)=\frac{x^3-1}{x+1}$. But none of them worked.

Comment: Did you try $(x^2+x+1)^{1/3}$ ?

Comment: @Peter I don't think the derivative is less than $1$, is it?

Comment: @Peter Ok I'm gonna try it... Should I assume $x\in [1,2]$?

Comment: @Peter the derivative is not less than $1$

Comment: According to Wolfram alpha, the minimum of the deivate in the interval [0,2] is $\frac{1}{3}$ and the maximum less than $0.5$. So, the iteration should converge.

Comment: @Peter Are u sure? I plotted this with GraphSketch ... see https://ibb.co/cyRSi6

Comment: Then check the input. I got the same result with PARI/GP.

Comment: I agree with @Peter. If $F(x) = \sqrt[3]{x^2+x+1}$, I get $0<F'(x)<1/3^{2/3} \approx 0.48$ for all $x>0$. The maximum occurs at $x=1$.

Comment: In what important way does the $f$ function intervene? It is not a matter of simply finding a contracting function that converges to a given point?

Comment: @Piquito Do you mean that I overlooked that the iteration should converge for every initial start-value ? Just because I realized this now.

Comment: @Peter: It is true that the starting point is arbitrary and also that if $g$ is not contracting but some of its iterates is, it is also worth the fixed point theorem for $g$. What I have meant is that Arman wants $g$ to converge to a given root point of $f$ but that point could be any other not in relation to $f$ and the problem would be the same qualitatively. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $x>0$, the equation is equivalent to
$$x^2+x+1=x^3\Leftrightarrow x+1+\frac{1}{x}=x^2 \Leftrightarrow g(x)=x$$
where $$g(x):=\sqrt{1+x+\frac{1}{x}}.$$
The function $g$ is a contraction in $[1,+\infty)$ because $g([1,+\infty))\subseteq [1,+\infty)$ and for $x\geq 1$,
$$0\leq g'(x)=\frac{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}{2\sqrt{1+x+\frac{1}{x}}}<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}<0.2887.$$
Hence, for any $x_0\geq 1$, the recurrence sequence $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$ converges to the unique fixed point $\alpha$ (and $f(\alpha)=0$). Actually also $x_0\in(0,1)$ is fine because $x_1=g(x_0)\geq 1$.

For example, if $x_0=1$ then
$$x_1=1.73205,\;
x_2=1.81917,\;
x_3=1.83544,\;
x_4=1.83855,\;
x_5=1.83914.$$

Comment: Thanks, I got my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

In the scalar case, the Newton method is guaranteed to converge over any interval (containing a root) where the function is monotonically increasing and concave (change the sign of the function or the sign of the argument for the other 3 cases, changing rising to falling or convex to concave, see Darboux theorem). Then if the initial point is left of the root, that has a negative function value, the root of the tangent will always come to again lie to the left of the root of the function, giving an increasing sequence of iteration points that eventually converges quadratically.

For a polynomial with exactly one sign change in the sequence of coefficients this situation can be obtained by dividing with a power of $x$ so that in the result positive powers have positive coefficients and negative powers negative coefficients. In the present case this give the function
$$h(x)=f(x)/x^3=1-x^{-1}-x^{-2}-x^{-3}$$
where each term is monotonically increasing and concave over the positive half axis, which implies the same property for the full expression. One can easily confirm that the function value at $x=1$ and also $x=\frac32$ is negatve, giving the interval $(0,\frac32)$ for initial values.

The Newton method for $h$ gives the fixed point iteration
\begin{align}
x_+=g(x)&=x-\frac{h(x)}{h'(x)}\\[.5em]
&=x-\frac{1-x^{-1}-x^{-2}-x^{-3}}{x^{-2}+2x^{-3}+3x^{-4}}\\[.5em]
&=x-x\frac{x^3-x^{2}-x-1}{x^{2}+2x+3}\\[.5em]
&=x\cdot\frac{-x^3+2x^2+3x+4}{x^2+2x+3}\\[.5em]
\end{align}

The iteration starting from $x_0=1.2345$ as arbitrary initial value gives

```
x[ 0]= 1.234500000000000, f(x[ 0])=-1.877124286375000
x[ 1]= 1.565876113606041, f(x[ 1])=-1.178365989290387
x[ 2]= 1.780838286905480, f(x[ 2])=-0.304499453179715
x[ 3]= 1.836551926465144, f(x[ 3])=-0.014926710896395
x[ 4]= 1.839280734591210, f(x[ 4])=-0.000032934773838
x[ 5]= 1.839286755184975, f(x[ 5])=-0.000000000159659
x[ 6]= 1.839286755214161, f(x[ 6])= 0.000000000000000
```

Comment: Yes, and the $x_+=g(x)$ is a fixed-point iteration. The Newton method is a special case in the class of fixed point iterations of the form $x_+=x-q(x)f(x)$.

Comment: OK, forget my comment.

Comment: By the way: Convex and decreasing would also work…

Comment: @Dirk : This is what is meant with changing the sign of the function and argument as that reflects about x and y axes, changing rising to falling and convex to concave and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing that the root is close to $2$, division with remainder gives $$f(x)=(x-2)(x^2+x+1)+1$$ leading to the iteration 
$$
x_{n+1}=g(x_n)=2-\frac1{1+x_n+x_n^2}
$$
which converges for $x_0\ge1$.

---

One gets contraction on $[1,\infty)$ as
$$
|g(y)-g(x)|=\frac{|1+x+y|}{(1+x+x^2)(1+y+y^2)}\,|y-x|\le\frac1{(x+\frac1{1+x})(y+\frac1{1+y})}\,|y-x|\le\frac49\,|y-x|.
$$
Also $g([1,∞))=[\frac53,2)\subset[1,∞)$.

---

An example iteration is

```
x[ 0]= 1.234500000000000, f(x[ 0])=-1.877124286375000
x[ 1]= 1.733935720599515, f(x[ 1])=-0.527333695696158
x[ 2]= 1.825798199731845, f(x[ 2])=-0.072967640174318
x[ 3]= 1.837644870408343, f(x[ 3])=-0.008969516018651
x[ 4]= 1.839088171630494, f(x[ 4])=-0.001086144304223
x[ 5]= 1.839262755473114, f(x[ 5])=-0.000131284472260
x[ 6]= 1.839283855007393, f(x[ 6])=-0.000015865119096
x[ 7]= 1.839286404747722, f(x[ 7])=-0.000001917174861
x[ 8]= 1.839286712863196, f(x[ 8])=-0.000000231674756
x[ 9]= 1.839286750096399, f(x[ 9])=-0.000000027995971
x[10]= 1.839286754595722, f(x[10])=-0.000000003383080
x[11]= 1.839286755139428, f(x[11])=-0.000000000408817
x[12]= 1.839286755205130, f(x[12])=-0.000000000049402
x[13]= 1.839286755213070, f(x[13])=-0.000000000005970
x[14]= 1.839286755214029, f(x[14])=-0.000000000000721
x[15]= 1.839286755214145, f(x[15])=-0.000000000000087
x[16]= 1.839286755214159, f(x[16])=-0.000000000000011
x[17]= 1.839286755214161, f(x[17])=-0.000000000000001
```

---

Using Aitken's delta-squared iteration speeds this up again to quadratic convergence using $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{(g(x_n))-x_n)^2}{g(g(x_n)-2g(x_n)+x_n}$$ shortening the example iteration to

```
x[ 0]= 1.234500000000000, f(x[ 0])=-1.877124286375000
x[ 1]= 1.846502981630578, f(x[ 1])= 0.039710950038240
x[ 2]= 1.839287216927013, f(x[ 2])= 0.000002525733614
x[ 3]= 1.839286755214163, f(x[ 3])= 0.000000000000010
x[ 4]= 1.839286755214161, f(x[ 4])= 0.000000000000000
```

Note that here the third step using 9 evaluations of $g$ is as good as the 16th step of the original iteration.